# Unconventional dependency name in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a few dependencies like this. For example : jdic

In my pom.xml, I defined a dependency

```
<dependency>
<artifactId>jdic</artifactId>
<groupId>jdic</groupId>
<version>0.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have a remote repository (internal server): eg http://repo/thirdparty/
And jdic can be found in http://repo/thirdparty/jdic/jar/jdic.jar

As you notice, the naming is not conventional groupId:artifactId:version, instead its just jdic.jar

so when I run maven compile

```
mvn clean compile
```

maven tells me that it cannot resolve dependencies. 
I'm aware that we can just download those jars to the local repository .m2/repository and run

```
mvn compile (ie without clean)
```

and it the jar will not be a problem. But is there any other way that I can make it retrieve from the remote despite its unconventional name and lack of metadata/pom info for those dependencies?

I already have a mirror to this internal repository that overrides the central

Answer (score 0):

You could install the jdic in your internal/mirror repository with the version (`jdic-0.8.6.jar`).

If you are using a repository manager and you uploaded the jar to it, it would automagically create a pom for it as well as ensure the dependency was created with version, as per maven convention.

Comment: I created another local repository called .maven3 . In my project's settings.xml, I redefined <localSettings>${user.home}/.maven3/repository</localRepository> (can it take property ${user.home}?)

Then I installed jdic's jar into ~/.maven3/repository/jdic/jdic/0.8.6/jdic-0.8.6.jar 

for which jdic-0.8.6.jar is a symbolic link to jdic.jar

then i ran mvn install

it still fails to download the dependency

Comment: I just found out that if i put ${user.home}/.maven3/repository</localRepository> , the local repository is now myProjectnameWhereIRunMaven/~/.maven3/repository

odd...

Answer (score 0):

A remote Maven repository is NOT any web server putting files in any way you want.  There are lots of convention to follow.  One of them is the way to represent the version  (which is one essential element of an artifact).  With your "remote repository" it is clear that there is no way Maven can find the artifact.

Setup a real Maven remote repository to host such files.  You can have a look in Nexus and Artifactory.

Comment: What is the file structure for a maven repository? I tried installing the jar manually to the local repository and run mvn install and the dependency still fails to resolve.

Comment: you shouldn't care about the file structure.  Google for "maven install third party lib" and learn how to properly install an artifact for use of Maven2/3.  And, I am talking about remote repository, not local repo. (And you said in your post that you are OK if you are installing the JAR in local repo, but now you said it is not working?  Can you please make your problem clear?)

Comment: If I install the jar into the local repo its fine because Maven checks the local repo first. But what I want is to download it from a remote repo that is a Maven 1 repo. Its not finding the jars in remote repo most likely because its Maven 1 repo. .. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: but in first comment you said "installing... to the local repository... fails to resolve".  Anyway, get Nexus and use 5 minutes to make a local repository, that's the easiest way and you can use it for remote repo proxying too.